# Jascrip, php, navegador, [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 36ms

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome, navegador-web

la pagina carga pero cuando intento ingresar informacion no me deja

me salen estor errores y no se que hacer no medeja ingresar informacion a mi proyecto alguien me puede ayudar, que debo hacer, para que funcione.

---

```
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 45ms
lista_de_servicios.php:1 

[DOM] Input elements should have autocomplete attributes (suggested: autocomplete='address-level1', confirm at[www.goo.gl/6KgkJg][1]) 
<select class=​"form-control" id=​"estado" name=​"estado" required>​…​</select>​<option value>​-- Selecciona estado --​</option>​<option value=​"1" selected>​Activo​</option>​<option value=​"0">​Inactivo​</option>​</select>​
    lista_de_servicios.php:1 

[DOM] Input elements should have autocomplete attributes (suggested: autocomplete='tel-local', confirm at[www.goo.gl/6KgkJg][1]) 
<input type=​"text" class=​"form-control" id=​"pre" name=​"pre" placeholder=​"Precio de venta del producto" required pattern=​"^[0-9]​{1,5}​(\.[0-9]​{0,2}​)​?$" title=​"Ingresa sólo números con 0 ó 2 decimales" maxlength=​"8">​
```

---

cuando intento ingresar información me sale 4 mas errores del mismo tipo por cada input y son 4 intpus cuatro errores mas.

Comment: Las imágenes, no sólo hacen imposible copiarlas, sino que también pueden ser difíciles de leer (pensemos en celulares que no definan bien la imagen o en personas con problemas de vista). ¿Podrías por favor incluirel mensaje de error como texto? Encontrarás el enlace para **[edit]** debajo de tu pregunta. Luego de pegarlo, hay que seleccionar el código completamente y hacer click en el botón `{  }`.

Comment: Gracias @Mariano... tu sabes hacerca del problema que sera o como puedo repararlo para que funcione. ya que ese error no me deja ingresar info a mi bd

Comment: Esos mensajes no son errores, son avisos, y no deberían afectar el ingreso de información (por cierto, ¿a qué te refieres con eso?). Debe haber algo más en el código que cause un fallo. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] y comparte algo de código en tu pregunta para que podamos ver un ejemplo con el fallo.